# Evaluating $\sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}} (n-2r+1)^2 \binom{n}{2r-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> I am seeking to evaluate the sum $$S=\sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}} (n-2r+1)^2 \binom{n}{2r-1} \\ =(n-1)^2 \binom{n}{1}+(n-3)^2 \binom{n}{3}+(n-5)^2\binom{n}{5}+\cdots$$

I re-wrote the sum as $$S=(n+1)^2\sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}} \binom{n}{2r-1}-4(n+1)\sum_{r\in\mathbb{N}}r\binom{n}{2r-1}+4\sum_{r\in\mathbb{N}}r^2\binom{n}{2r-1}$$

It is clear from the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$, (by plugging $x=\pm1$ ) we get the value of the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{r\in\mathbb{N}}\binom{n}{2r-1}$ as $2^{n-1}$.

Now, after this I **can** find the value of the sums $\displaystyle \sum_{r\in\mathbb{N}}r\binom{n}{2r-1}$ and  $\displaystyle \sum_{r\in\mathbb{N}}r^2\binom{n}{2r-1}$ by considering the binomial expansion of $\displaystyle \dfrac{(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n}{2}$ and substituting $x$ for $\sqrt{x}$ and then differentiating, and by manipulations, I will be able to find the desired sums.

However, this method gets very lengthy, especially when doing differentiation for finding  $\displaystyle \sum_{r\in\mathbb{N}}r^2\binom{n}{2r-1}$.

I am hoping to see some other different approaches which don't involve so much calculation and are easy to understand.

---

The final closed form is $n(n+1)2^{n-3}$.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1353963/573047) can be useful.

Comment: @BillyJoe: I am aware of that post already actually, I saw that before I asked this question, but I am not much familiar with stirling numbers of second kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite the sum as:

$$\begin{aligned}S&=\sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}} (n-2r+1)^2 {n \choose 2r-1} \\&= \sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}} (n-2r+1)^2 {n \choose n-2r+1} \\&= \sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}} (n-2r+1)^2 \frac{n!}{(n-2r+1)!(2r-1)!} \\&= \sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}} n(n-2r+1) \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-2r)!(2r-1)!} \\&= \sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}} n(n-2r+1) {n-1 \choose 2r-1} \\&= n^2 \sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}} {n-1 \choose 2r-1} - n \sum_{r \in \mathbb{N}} (2r-1){n-1 \choose 2r-1} \\&= n^2 \frac{2^{n-1}}{2} - n(n-1) \frac{2^{n-2}}{2} \\&= n2^{n-3}(2n-n+1) \\&= n(n+1)2^{n-3}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Now I am wondering why didn't I think of this?!

Answer (score 2):

For a combinatorial proof, consider choosing from $n$ people a committee with an odd number of regular members and a secretary and treasurer (which might be the same person).  The LHS conditions on the number $2r-1$ of regular members.  The RHS first selects the secretary and treasurer and then selects an odd number of remaining members.  If one person is both secretary and treasurer, then half of the subsets of the remaining $n-1$ people are odd.  If the secretary and treasurer are different people, then half of the subsets of the remaining $n-2$ people are odd.  The sum of the two counts is:
$$n\cdot\frac{2^{n-1}}{2} + n(n-1) \frac{2^{n-2}}{2} = (2n+(n^2-n))2^{n-3} = n(n+1)2^{n-3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let

$$(n-2r+1)^2=a+b(2r-1)+c(2r-1)(2r-2)$$

Set $2r-1=0\implies a=n^2$

$2r-2=0\implies a+b=(n-1)^2\implies b=?$

Compare the coefficients of $r^2,c=1$

Now $$(2r-1)(2r-2)\cdot\binom n{2r-1}=n(n-1)\binom{n-2}{2r-3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the chain rule.

$$ f(x)=\displaystyle \dfrac{(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n}{2}$$

We want $\frac{d^2 f(\sqrt{x})}{dx^2}$ which can be simplified as:

$$ \frac{d^2 f(\sqrt{x} )}{dx^2} = \frac12  \frac{d}{dx}( \frac{df}{dx}|_{\sqrt{x} } \frac{1}{ \sqrt{x}}) =\frac12 \left[ \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}|_{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{2x} -\frac{1}{2} \frac{df}{dx}|_{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{x^{\frac32}}\right] $$

Now, here's the interesting part put $x=1$

$$ \frac{d^2 f \circ (\sqrt{x})}{dx^2}|_{x=1}= \frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}|_{1} - \frac{df}{dx}|_{1} \right]$$

And, the right side is now easy to evaluate on the given expression

Comment: I am not being rude, but I have already written about this in my post, so what do you add extra? Besides, you haven't even calculated the final answer.

Comment: Because, you had simply told to take the derivative by brute forcing. I just wanted to lay out the game plan on how to solve it , not give you the full answer because you will gain nothing of it @LightYagami

Comment: I wrote, I **can** evaluate those sums using differentiation. So, I knew the "game plan", didn't I?

Comment: You claimed a lengthy differentiation, the chain rule way of doing it takes less than a minute :P

Comment: Of course, one would use the chain rule to differentiate, what else do you think I am using to differentiate? For me, it gets difficult to keep track of those terms, so for doing it completely carefully, I would take more than one minute.

Comment: By saying to use chain rule, I mean to work out the expression before actually plugging in it and making (1+sqrt(x) )^n and expanding. The way I have done it (withotu plugging in) , gives a much more 'nicer' thing to evaluate in the end because the square roots go away once the x=1 is plugged